# Access the Chrome Storage API from chrome://print

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, printing

I have a number of different reports that I have to print out from the web on a pretty regular basis at work. I have to print enough of these reports frequently enough that I've grown tired of hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, selecting the appropriate paper size and number of copies umpteen times a day.

I've got some working code that will open the print menu as soon as I open one of these reports. I can change paper size, copies, etc. and click the "print" button through JavaScript, but my problem is that I need some way to configure my print settings based on the page that I'm printing.

This is where the Chrome storage API comes in. From what I can tell, the print menu's `document.referrer` property will always return null. My plan thus far has been to use Chrome's Storage API to set and retrieve a property called `activeReport` to determine the appropriate print settings for the current document. I have this bit of code at the very top of my content script for debugging purposes:

```
 chrome.storage.local.get(appData, function(vars){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(vars));
 });
```

This prints out all of the current properties of the `appData` object when I visit any webpage, with the exception of `chrome://print`, which prints the below error message to the console.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.get: Access to extension API denied.
```

I've enabled the "allow extensions on Chrome URLs" flag and added `chrome://print/*` to my permissions in my manifest file. I've successfully manipulated the print menu's DOM using my extension, but I cannot seem to access the storage API. Does anyone know if I have to set any additional permissions to use the storage API on these URLs?

Barring that, does anyone have any suggestions on alternative ways that I could get the URL of the parent window while the print menu is open? The `Window.Parent` method doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure if I could reasonably have access to the tabs API if I don't have access to the storage API, although that's what I'm going to try next.

Comment: See if `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` works.

Comment: I ended up creating an event page using runtime.onConnect. I found that using the one-off exchange template that google suggests didn't work because the event page was being unloaded before it could reply, so I had to create a listener for the first message, and then I needed to listen for a followup message to guarantee a successful exchange.

I'm not very happy with this solution though. The rest of my extension uses local storage, and my event page is basically a proxy for the storage api. The result is messy, harder to maintain code, but it gets the job done for now.

Comment: @Makyen Can you remove your lengthy comments? The question is already very clear in its current form.

Comment: @D.Truitt Using extension messaging seems to be the only reliable way. You can also communicate settings via side channels such as document.title or the URL of the page, but extension messaging seems the best solution for your case. I have also reported the bug that you described at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685588